# connect two sockets from one client

Tags: c++, sockets

I am newbie in sockets. I am writing a clent-server application and I got the following issue.

Clent:

```
void * msgDispatcher(...){
   ...
   while(isRunning){
      read(rxSocket, buf, ...);
   }
}

int main(...){
   ...
   connect(txSocket, ...);
   connect(rxSocket, ...);

   createThread(..., msgDispatcher, ...);
   while(isRunning){
      fgets(buf, ...);
      write(txSocket, buf, ...);
  }
}
```

Server:

```
int main(...){
   ...
   listenerSocket = socket(...);
   bind(listenerSocket,...);

   listen(listenerSocket, 10);
   rxSocket = accept(listenerSocket, (sockaddr*) &clientAddr, &addrLength);

   listen(listenerSocket, 10);
   txSocket = accept(listenerSocket, (sockaddr*)  &clientAddr, &addrLength);

   while(isRunning){
      read(rxSocket, ...);
      write(txSocket, ...);
   }
}
```

All messages that I send from the client are received on the server, but all responses from the server are not received on the client.
Server sends messages using *write(txSocket, ...);* and there are no issues here. But client is waiting all time on the *read(rxSocket, ...)* and there are no msgs are received.

What is incorrect in this code? How to connect/accept two sockets from one client on the server or is there the best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Why you use two socket, one for RX and another for TX? connection oriented sockets are bidirectional!

Comment: How do you ensure that the servers's txSocket is the same as the client's rxSocket? Can't see it from your code.

Comment: BigBoss, I use two sockets because I need to send new requests from the client without waiting for a response from the server. But also I need to receive responses from the server and I've created new thread to read socket. If I use the same socket, the reading blocks the socket(I am planning the response can be sent over 1 min for example) and I cannot send a new request.

Comment: Zane, I think that the txSocket on the server is not corresponded to rxSocket on the client and it causes the issue). I don't know how to check it. And how to do that txSocket on the server will be corresponded to the clinet socket. I supposed my code do it (the second connect on the client is for rxSocket and the second accept on the server is for txSocket).

Comment: You don't need two sockets for that.  The client can send as much as it wants to the server before checking for data from the server.  There's no reason why the client must wait for a response before sending another request on the same socket.  Read about [HTTP pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining), for example.

Comment: According to the comment in the answer, the problem was an unspecified typo in the code. Voting to close as too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I digged some hours today and return the code as in the question. Two sockets work fine now. RxSocket on client receives all messages from the server and TxSocket sends messages to the server.
Looks like it was a typo in the code.

P.S. listen() function can be invoked only one time, but calling twice does not affect anything.